# Customize ribbons for every MS Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, ribbonx

I am new to development with VBA. I am working on a project based on MS Word macros.
Lately, I have been trying to create ribbons to access certain functionalities, but I have got limited success in it.
I want to customize ribbons using XML which should appear on all MS Word files and not the one I have used to customize ribbon.
Is there any way to create any XML file that can be utilised by all MS word documents without having to customize each one of them.

Thanks..
Regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this is essentially the same as for making macros available to all documents:

Store the Ribbon in a *template* (together with the macros, so a dotm) and load it as an Add-in.

If it should load automatically, that means placing it in Word's STARTUP folder.

Comment: Hi Cindy, thanks for the prompt reply. I followed on with your solution. The ribbon appears in all the word document. But, on calling the macro, it shows the error " Compile error in hidden module: userform1" the UserForm is the called inside the macro that runs on clicking the button in the ribbon. I am not sure what is the issue now.

Comment: SOLVED: The issue was of keeping the project protected. It worked when I rremoved the password for protection. PS: Please let us all know if there is any way to do it with keeping the project protected.

Comment: @PushpendraSingh Please note that the Stack Overflow concept is one issue per question. The site is not a typical "forum" where there might be an on-going discussion as a problem evolves. The correct procedure is to ask a ***new*** question for a new problem. Be sure to include enough information for people to be able to follow/reproduce (linking to another discussion is also possible). Here, for example, we have no idea what kind of protection is involved, nor what, exactly, you ended up doing.

Comment: @cindyMiester I am new to Stack Overflow. I ll take care of it hence forth. With regards to the details of the follow up problem, I don't think creating separate question is required. The protection I am indicating is using password to protect the project from viewing. Please let me know if you can help.

Comment: @PushpendraSingh This does require a separate question, with all relevant information, including the steps to recreate the situation. I know it may seem quite clear to you and I *think* I understand what you're saying, but I'm not sure. And over more than 20 years doing on-line support I've learned never to assume I understand when something isn't 100% clear... Also, if you ask a separate question others, who may have already experienced the problem (I have not) have a chance to see the question. Here, no one but the two of us are likely reading this...